# Reagarding unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies

while installing the openssh server using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bcmwl-kernel-source : Depends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
 debhelper : Depends: dh-apparmor but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will install any and all unmet dependencies and complete the installation of whatever it was you were trying to install that did not complete as a result of said unmet dependencies.